# prep + nouns or prep + verbing

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction

> I have collaborated with David in funding applications and paper
>   writing.
>   I have collaborated with David in applying for fundings
>   and writing papers.

which sentence sounds more natural to native ears? and the reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second sentence is better, except that "fundings" might be better as a non-count noun. The problem with the first sentence is that "funding applications" could be read as a verb followed by a direct object.

Comment: thank you, what if I rearrange the first sentence: I have collaborated with David in paper writing and funding applications. Then the problem of confusion solved. Which sentence is better now?

Comment: "Funding applications" can still be read as verb+object. The second sentence doesn't have that ambiguity, and it has the style advantage of using the two verbs "applying" and "writing" in a parallel way.